# Android async task - which activity evoked it?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am facing problem of having one async task, but I need it use twice, because each time I change  different part of GUI (updating progress bar).

Is there any way how to determine in if - else clause, which activity does it call and then make appropriate function for each of both of them?

**Edit:** huh, answer was here and now there isn't...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold a member variable which contains the activity/context it is started from.

```
//pseudocode
AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask();
task.mActivity = this;
task.execute();
```

Inside `doInBackground` just check the activity:

```
//pseudocode
if (mActivity instanceof MyActivity) {
    // ....
} else {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the code from the AsyncTask implementation and delegate that to the Activity. Example:

```
public interface MyDelegate {
    public void updateProgress(....)
}
```

Your AsyncTask takes a delegate and calls it when appropiate:

```
public class MyAsyncTask .... {
    public MyAsyncTask(MyDelegate myDelegate) { ... }

    // somewhere in your code (probably onProgressUpdate)
    myDelegate.updateProgress(...)
}
```

Your Activity/ies implement/s the delegate:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyDelegate {
   public void updateProgress(...) {
       // update ui
   }

   // somewhere in your code:
   new MyAsyncTask(this).execute(...);
}
```